# html percentage not correct

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myContainer {
            background-color: #000000;
            opacity: 0.7;
            height: 70%;
            width: 70%;
            margin-top: 15%;
            margin-left:15%;


        }
</style>
</head>
   <body>
           <div id="myContainer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to center my div and its logic seems to be ok, because I gave it 70% of width and height, 30% remains, for centering `<div id="myContainer">` I will just need a 15% margin.but it's just horizontally centered and not vertically.

what should I do?

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add the property in css selector of 'position' and set value 'relative' or 'absolute' then it will work I think.

#myContainer {
    background-color: #000000;
    opacity: 0.7;
    height: 70%;
    width: 70%;
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-left:15%;
    position: absolute;
}

Comment: you can try `margin-top:15vh` and `margin-left:15vw` but i wouldn't recommend this..

Comment: @ShadowFiend thanks, this worked, but why not recommending?

Comment: When using percentages with value of margin property，it’s percentages is referred to it's parent dom’s width, if the height of the dom is not equal to width, the 15% will not work.